# How get array value by key in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting following *javascript* array and i need to get value of that array by key. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

```
[Object { 5=7224}, Object { 10=7225}, Object { 25=7226}, Object { 50=7227}]
```

I have created following code -

```
'payment_tariff': {
    4142: 
        {  
            1: [{1: 7223}],
            2: [{5: 7224}, {10: 7225}, {25: 7226}, {50: 7227}],
            3: [{10: 7228}, {20: 7229}, {50: 7230}, {100: 7231}],
            4: [{25: 7232}, {50: 7233}, {100: 7234}, {250: 7235}],
            5: [{25: 7236}, {50: 7237}, {100: 7238}, {250: 7239}]
        }
    ,
    4130: 
        {
            1: [{1: 7132}],
            2: [{5: 7133}, {10: 7134}, {25: 7135}, {50: 7136}],
            3: [{10: 7137}, {25: 7138}, {50: 7139}, {100: 7140}],
            4: [{25: 7141}, {50: 7142}, {100: 7143}, {250: 7144}],
            5: [{25: 7145}, {50: 7146}, {100: 7147}, {250: 7148}]
        }
    ,
    4133: 
        {
            1: [{1: 7166}],
            2: [{5: 7167}, {10: 7168}, {25: 7169}, {50: 7170}],
            3: [{10: 7171}, {25: 7172}, {50: 7173}, {100: 7173}],
            4: [{25: 7174}, {50: 7175}, {100: 7176}, {250: 7177}],
            5: [{25: 7178}, {50: 7179}, {100: 7180}, {250: 7181}]
        }
    ,
    4134: 
        {
            1: [{1: 7188}],
            2: [{5: 7189}, {10: 7190}, {25: 7191}, {50: 7192}],
            3: [{10: 7193}, {25: 7194}, {50: 7195}, {100: 7298}],
            4: [{25: 7197}, {50: 7198}, {100: 7199}, {250: 7200}],
            5: [{25: 7201}, {50: 7202}, {100: 7203}, {250: 7204}]
        }
    ,
    4135: 
        {
            1: [{1: 7206}],
            2: [{5: 7207}, {10: 7208}, {25: 7209}, {50: 7210}],
            3: [{10: 7211}, {25: 7212}, {50: 7213}, {100: 7214}],
            4: [{25: 7215}, {50: 7216}, {100: 7217}, {250: 7218}],
            5: [{25: 7219}, {50: 7220}, {100: 7221}, {250: 7222}]
        }

}
```

I am getting dynamic value of payment_tariff's keys

For example, I need to get value of key 5, Where key is some value that will be further processed.

Comment: Unique keys in each object? That's painful. Is it something you can change, or is it out of your control?

Comment: Use computed indexing `[...]`

Comment: Given **payment_tariff** what is your expected result?

Comment: Where is the value located / lookup needed? if it is in `payment_tariff` - use `payment_tariff[Key]` which will return you an object from where you would need further lookup.

Comment: Hi JonSG, 
I am getting value for payment_tariff[4142][2] as  [Object { 5=7224}, Object { 10=7225}, Object { 25=7226}, Object { 50=7227}] so i need to get value of object payment_tariff[4142][2] index 5 or any of keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not 100% sure about what you want as a result, but I think given **payment_tariff** and two values (4142 and 2), you want an array of keys from the array of objects that those values identify.

I updated the demo to return an array of keys and values as I suspect you might want that. If this is not the result you seek then please specify **exactly** what the result is you do seek.

```js
var data = {
  'payment_tariff': {
    4142: {
      1: [{1: 7223}],
      2: [{5: 7224}, {10: 7225}, {25: 7226}, {50: 7227}],
      3: [{10: 7228}, {20: 7229}, {50: 7230}, {100: 7231}],
      4: [{25: 7232}, {50: 7233}, {100: 7234}, {250: 7235}],
      5: [{25: 7236}, {50: 7237}, {100: 7238}, {250: 7239}]
    },
    4130: {
      1: [{1: 7132}],
      2: [{5: 7133}, {10: 7134}, {25: 7135}, {50: 7136}],
      3: [{10: 7137}, {25: 7138}, {50: 7139}, {100: 7140}],
      4: [{25: 7141}, {50: 7142}, {100: 7143}, {250: 7144}],
      5: [{25: 7145}, {50: 7146}, {100: 7147}, {250: 7148}]
    },
    4133: {
      1: [{1: 7166}],
      2: [{5: 7167}, {10: 7168}, {25: 7169}, {50: 7170}],
      3: [{10: 7171}, {25: 7172}, {50: 7173}, {100: 7173}],
      4: [{25: 7174}, {50: 7175}, {100: 7176}, {250: 7177}],
      5: [{25: 7178}, {50: 7179}, {100: 7180}, {250: 7181}]
    },
    4134: {
      1: [{1: 7188}],
      2: [{5: 7189}, {10: 7190}, {25: 7191}, {50: 7192}],
      3: [{10: 7193}, {25: 7194}, {50: 7195}, {100: 7298}],
      4: [{25: 7197}, {50: 7198}, {100: 7199}, {250: 7200}],
      5: [{25: 7201}, {50: 7202}, {100: 7203}, {250: 7204}]
    },
    4135: {
      1: [{1: 7206}],
      2: [{5: 7207}, {10: 7208}, {25: 7209}, {50: 7210}],
      3: [{10: 7211}, {25: 7212}, {50: 7213}, {100: 7214}],
      4: [{25: 7215}, {50: 7216}, {100: 7217}, {250: 7218}],
      5: [{25: 7219}, {50: 7220}, {100: 7221}, {250: 7222}]
    }
  }
};

var result = data.payment_tariff[4142][2].map(function(item){
  var key = Object.keys(item)[0];
  return { "key": key, "value": item[key] };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you, I wanted the same

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array with a list of fields ( keys ) of an object like this:

```
var keys = Object.keys(payment_tariff);
for(var i in keys) {
    var key_name = keys[i];
    console.log(key_name + " = " + payment_tariff[key_name]);
}
```

OBS: **payment_tariff** is the name of your variable/object/array;

More here: [Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: Thank you Edgard Leal for your quick response. I have edited the question, please check once my code